# How can i merge multiple jpg files completely into one pdf

Tags: images, conversion, merge, centos-7

[image]

I have multiple jpg files in a folder and i am using convert:
`convert *.jpg output.pdf` but the resulting pdf has separation between then as seem in the picture.How can i merge it completely without any seperation.

I have more jpgs here i need to automate this.
please suggest any command line way of doing this

Comment: If the files are all the same size, you can match the output page to the image size and get one image per page. Alternatively, you can make one very long page with all the images in, though that will make it difficult to print. See the `-page` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to do this using :

```
convert -append *.jpg out.pdf
```

Comment: That gives the very long page I suggested, but creates it a lot more easily.